Pyspark : How to get all last months to the current month?
In pyspark, I have this table, I want to get all the past months to this current month = 'September'



January
Febuary
March
April
May
June
July
August
September
October
November
December




10
20
30
40
50
60
70
80
100
110
120
150



Then, I will obtain this table at the end :



January
Febuary
March
April
May
June
July
August
September




10
20
30
40
50
60
70
80
100



This my code :
months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

for month in months:
   if month < (F.month(F.current_date())):
      df = df.filter(F.col(month))
```


define the current month
import datetime
index_of_current_month = datetime.datetime.now().month

Select months before and including the current month
df_selected = df.select(*months[:index_of_current_month])


You can try using this code snippet
# initialising spark 
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("FilterPastMonths").getOrCreate()

months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

# Create a dict to map month-names to their corresponding month nos
month_mapping = {month: index + 1 for index, month in enumerate(months)}

current_month_row = spark.sql("SELECT month(current_date()) as current_month").collect()
current_month = current_month_row[0]["current_month"]

# filter the months to only include months up to the current month (e.g., September)
filtered_months = [
    month for month, month_num in month_mapping.items() if month_num <= current_month
]

# This should be your actual df 
data = [(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 100, 110, 120, 150)]
columns = months

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

# Select only the columns for the filtered months
df_filtered = df.select(filtered_months)

# Show the result
df_filtered.show()

Result:
Python version tested: 3.8

+-------+--------+-----+-----+---+----+----+------+---------+                   
|January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|
+-------+--------+-----+-----+---+----+----+------+---------+
|     10|      20|   30|   40| 50|  60|  70|    80|      100|
+-------+--------+-----+-----+---+----+----+------+---------+


